# Bootstrap datepicker is not attached to input field

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, styling, angular-ui-grid

I have a ui-grid with a cell that has a template that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div
    tooltip={{row.entity[col.field]}}
    tooltip-trigger="mouseenter"
    tooltip-placement="top"
    tooltip-popup-delay="100"
    tooltip-append-to-body="true"
    >
<input
        class="form-control tekstowe"
        ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD"
        options=grid.appScope.calendarOptions["DATE_TABLE"]
        date-time-picker
        ng-required="true"
        pattern="(\d{4})[-\/](\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})"
        ng-blur="grid.appScope.refreshOnChange && grid.appScope.isValidDate(MODEL_COL_FIELD) && grid.appScope.updateEntity(row)"
        />
</div>
```

date-time-picker is my custom directive that invokes bootstrap datetimepicker with specified options. Currently I use this set:

```
            format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
            language: 'pl',
            pickTime: false,
            asString: true,
            withTime: false
```

Datepicker works, but strangely it is not attached to an input filed. It appears at the right bottom corner. Actually, it enlarges my grid, so I have to scroll right and to the bottom to see it. All works fine, but it seems that styling is somehow flawed. I tried to delete class attribute from input tag - no success.

What is interesting, when I set vertical scrolls off in ui-grid settings, all works fine, and the datetimepicker shows at correct place (below input field).

[image: Datepicker wrong position]

What am I missing?

Comment: can you make a plnkr with this...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. In case of showing datepicker in a ui-grid I reassign position handling dp.show event. This is not a pretty solution (very ugly one, actually) but it works.

```
                $element
                .datetimepicker($scope.options)
                .on("dp.show", function(e) {
                    if ($scope.options.uiGridTable) {
                        var ele = $(e.target).data('DateTimePicker');
                        if (ele.widget.position().top > 0) {
                            ele.widget.css('top', ele.element.position().top + ROW_HEIGHT);
                        }
                        if (ele.widget.position().left > 0) {
                            ele.widget.css('left', ele.element.position().left);
                        }
                    }
                })
```